# Можно ли из HashMap сделать Json?

Tags: java, android, сервер

У меня есть

```
private Map<Image, HashMap<String, Float>> metadataMap;
```

вот такой `metadataMap` и есть вот такой [хост](https://www.000webhost.com/), как я могу сделать из него Json чтоб отправить его на хост чтоб там его смогли получить и работать с данными?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. Можете в цикле вручную все складывать, можете просто сделать:

```
new JSONObject(metadataMap);
```

Comment: Я вот только подумал... А как картинки конвертируются в String? С этим будут проблемы?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, будут. Никак они не конвертируются. Тем более, никто не знает, в каком виде их ожидает ваш сервер

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, в строку никак, можно в массив байтов